# How can I properly pass data into a view intended for html email template in Codeigniter4?

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I am trying to pass data into a view from which contents will be sent as an html email. The view file is loading properly and email delivers except that it doesn't show the data I have passed alongside.

Below is the code

Controller

```
<?php 

$content = '<p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 140%; text-align: center;"> <span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 22.4px;"> This is a content to be passed </span> </p>';
                
$item = [
    'title' => 'This is an amazing title',
    'message' => $content
];
                    
$message = view('email_template', $item); //email_template is a view that loads fine but the $item is not accessed inside of it.

?>
```

//email_template.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php print_r($item) ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use $title instead

Comment: There is a CodeIgniter Userguide that explains this (see the CodeIgniter Website). It might be really worth your time reading up on it. You've set it up correctly in the controller... Now you have access to the variables $title and $message in your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

$data['content'] = '<p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 140%; text-align: center;"> <span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 22.4px;"> This is a content to be passed </span> </p>';
                
$data['item'] = [
    'title' => 'This is an amazing title',
    'message' => $content
];
                    
$message = view('email_template', $data); //email_template is a view that loads fine but the $item is not accessed inside of it.

?>
```

Then in your view you'll have access to your array keys as variables.

So to access the $data['content'] you'll use:

```
<?php echo $content ?>
```

To access the title and message:

```
<?php echo $item['title'] ?>

<?php echo $item['message'] ?>
```

To know more about how to send data to the view you can check the documentation here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/views.html?highlight=views#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get item in `view` use array like this

```
$item['item'] = [
    'title' => 'This is an amazing title',
    'message' => $content
];
```

one more function using `compact`

```
$item = [
    'title' => 'This is an amazing title',
    'message' => $content
];
$message = view('email_template', compact('item'));
```